# How can I get the Id after the row have been imported in the Django Admin with Django-import-export?

Tags: django-admin, django-import-export

Currently, I can access some data before or after to save the instance in the DB. But I couldn't get the ID after the row was import

```
class OtherResource(resources.ModelResource):
   """
   My code
   """               
   def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, **kwargs):
       my_class= MyClass.objects.get(id=row['id'])
       my_class.first_name = 'some new'
       recipient.save()

class MyClassAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

   resource_class = OtherResource

   def import_data(self, dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False, use_transactions=None, collect_failed_rows=False, **kwargs):
       """
       Getting the user's request to pass it to the import
       """
       result = OtherResource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False, use_transactions=None, user=self.request.user)
    return result
```

Dango says the query doesn't exist, because I couldn't get the id

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the row after its imported by overriding the `after_import_row` method in this manner:

```
    def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, **kwargs):
        print(row_result.object_id) # <-- new row's ID
        if row_result.new_record:  # check if new entry is created OR old entry updated
            # custom code for newly created record
            pass
```